# How to know what action is triggering an event?

Tags: java, event-handling, printstacktrace

How do I know what action is triggering a particular event?

```
org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener refreshAnnotationsListener = new org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener() { 
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(org.w3c.dom.events.Event event) {
       // how do I know the action which triggered this event?
    }
};
```

I guess there is a way to print stack trace using "throw" which also displays the name of the action that is triggering an event. Am not exactly sure how to do this though. Or, is there another way of doing it ?

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a stacktrace any time you want, by creating an exception:

```
new Exception().printStackTrace();
```

You don't have to throw it.